# CSS in Tizen WebView (EFL WebKit) wouldn't honor font-family

Tags: html, css, webview, tizen, tizen-native-app

I am rendering some HTML using WebView based on EFL WebKit in Tizen 2.4 and 3.0 SDK.

```html
<div className="hexArea" id="hexArea1">
  Content
</div>
```

and corresponding CSS:

```css
.hexArea {
  position: relative;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: pre;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
  color: #0F0F0F;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

While this works perfectly well on several platforms such as Desktop, Android WebView, iOS WebView, it does not show fixed-font on the Tizen App.  I can't seem to set font for anything on the page.

I tried `style="font-family: 'monospace'"` on the `div`, I tried to make the CSS just `font-family: monospace`, but the html on the Tizen WebView just does not seem to honor `font-family`.

I am trying to display bytes in hex and decimal, and it looks horrible with normal font.  Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT: I even tried `<pre>` tag but shows in normal font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Fixed font resources seem to be not provided in the Tizen SDK by default. But it's possible to display a fixed-font in app side using CSS @font-face or the Google Font API.

- Use CSS @font-face with font resource.

  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face
  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

  I think you can add a fixed font resource in your app and load and display the font using CSS @font-face.
- Use Google Font API.

  https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto Mono">
    <style>
      .hexArea {
        font-family: "Roboto Mono";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>normal font:1234567890</div>
    <div class="hexArea">fixed-font:1234567890</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you..  I am unable to check now.. Will check soon and respond.